# How to connect to mainnet on website with web3js?

Tags: web3js

I have been searching and seeing similar questions but I don't really understand the answer. I have a very simple node.js application that does not involve smart contacts. All I want to do is check the balance of an ethereum address. I see this in the web3js documentation

`web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));`

but that is if I'm running a node on my server, which has a bunch of security issues on its own. Is there a provider I can use for mainnet to just check balances? If not why not?

Comment: Take a look at [Infura](https://infura.io).

Answer (score 3):

Use infura api.
Go to infura website and create your own infura key that will make a connection with ethereum block chain, and provide you stable node.
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://mainnet.infura.com/infurakey'));

Comment: Thank you! Just curious, are there other ways to do it or do you always need to use a service like that?

Comment: You was asking about the provider, that's why i mentioned that way.. you can also do that using geth but its seriously not a good idea according to me, because we need to take care alot of things with this procedure.so i prefer you to use this service provider.

Comment: I meant are there many service providers, or is there a collection of them somewhere?